# How to boot Centos 8 with volatile root overlay filesystem?

Tags: boot, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, overlay

Generally, I am looking to boot a Linux box so that the persistent storage is immutable. Any changes made to the filesystem should be lost when the box is powered off.

This is for system where the hardware is meant to run a single application, and (once past initial configuration) the system is meant to always come up in the exact same configuration, with no preserved state from the last run.

Done enough reading to expect this to be an overlay filesystem (overlayfs), with the lower as (fully configured) persistent storage, and the upper as either a tmpfs or a ramdisk. (Looks like tmpfs is more likely.) Configured w/o trouble an overlayfs with the root directory (/) as lower, and a tmpfs as upper (and work).

The trick is to overlay the root directory somewhat early in the boot process.

The complication here is that Redhat did a bit of re-invention with dracut and systemd, so most of the answers on the web do not quite apply. (Centos is derived from Redhat, or in present somewhat the converse -- as is Fedora.) The initramfs handling in Redhat is a bit different from everyone else.

Expect to come up with an answer, but posting the question for the next guy. :)

There is support in systemd that looks likely. The parameter "systemd.volatile=yes" on the kernel command line looks likely (though first tries failed to boot). Centos 8 comes with systemd 239, so ... not quite supported?

Could use systemd-nspawn to spin up the application in a container with overlaid root, maybe, but have not gone down this path as yet. Preferable to do the overlay on boot.

Looking for the cleanest approach to a root overlay on boot.

Comment: Why not just use a CentOS live USB?

Comment: The default CentOS live USB (from dd of iso to volume) is going to offer to install CentOS every time. Bit more pristine than I need. :)
Might be able to use that for hints?

Comment: You can just say no and continue.

Comment: Heh. This is an unattended device (no console) remote on the network, so not quite. :)

Comment: @PrestonL.Bannister did you find reliable way? Can you share any new solutions?